# Identifying incorrectly transformed data cells

Tags: r

I have a massive excel spreadsheet full of dates in `%m/%d/%Y` format. In R, I convert them date format using `as.Date`. The problem is that some of the dates in Excel were manually entered incorrectly, for example as section below where 214 was entered instead of 2014.

```
...
235     2014-01-20
236     2014-03-03
237     2014-01-24
238     2014-03-07
239      214-05-23
240     2014-01-31
241     2014-02-19
242     2014-03-27
...
```

For individual columns, I can use the function `which(dataframe$colname_X<1900)` which will give me the row number. This is easy because I already know which column it is.

My question is, how can I do the same to the entire dataframe, so that I get both row and column number of the faulty cells?.

Comment: do you have multiple columns with dates? If so you could use  `apply` to run the which function over all columns.   e.g. `apply(df, 2, function(x) which(x<1900))` That will return a list of results corresponding to each column with the indices with the errors.

Comment: @jalapic thank you, this is what I was looking for. the only slight inconvenience is that it returns the name of every column with the output `integer(0)` when the dates are entered correctly, or for example `[1] 239` if there was incorrect entry (my above example). It works great but if there were a really large amount of columns, I can see this output becoming cumbersome.

Comment: it should preserve column order. So you could save your original columns names like this `mycolnames <- colnames(df)` and then when you have the correct data just put them back like this `colnames(df) <-mycolnames`

Comment: @jalapic that's not the problem, the problem is if I have 50 columns with dates, and it returns all of them instead of selecting the columns with faulty entries: `$date.1
integer(0)

$date.2
integer(0)

$date.3
integer(0)

$date.4
integer(0)

$date.5
integer(0)

$date.6
integer(0)

$date.7
integer(0)

$date.8
integer(0)

$date.9
[1] 3
` . So ideally I would want it to skip first 8 columns and take me straingt to column `date.9`. Why don't you enter your solution as a separate answer

Comment: have done so -- let me know if it helps. Without reproducible data it's hard to do an exact example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One potential solution

identify all errors using `apply`

`results <- apply(df, 2, function(x) which(x<1900))`

This will return a list with each column as an element of the list.  As you don't care about those that are empty (i.e. no errors) you could contract the list to only keep those with errors:

`results[lapply(results,length)>0]`

Answer (score 2):

Starting with:

```
  dat <- rd.txt("235     2014-01-20  # #function to use read.table on text
 236     2014-03-03
 237     2014-01-24
 238     2014-03-07
 239      214-05-23
 240     2014-01-31
 241     2014-02-19
 242     2014-03-27")
 dat <- cbind(dat,dat)
 dat[] <- lapply(dat, as.Date, origin="1970-01-01")
> dat
        X235 X2014.01.20       X235 X2014.01.20
1 1970-08-25  2014-03-03 1970-08-25  2014-03-03
2 1970-08-26  2014-01-24 1970-08-26  2014-01-24
3 1970-08-27  2014-03-07 1970-08-27  2014-03-07
4 1970-08-28  0214-05-23 1970-08-28  0214-05-23
5 1970-08-29  2014-01-31 1970-08-29  2014-01-31
6 1970-08-30  2014-02-19 1970-08-30  2014-02-19
7 1970-08-31  2014-03-27 1970-08-31  2014-03-27
```

Now use `which` with arr.ind=TRUE (do need to convert to numeric matrix first)

```
which( sapply(dat,as.numeric) < (as.numeric(as.Date("1900-01-01") ) ), arr.ind=TRUE)
     row col
[1,]   4   2
[2,]   4   4
```

Comment: thank you, but the data frame has some factor columns so I would rather avoid subsetting and converting it and go with the above response.